# DATEDIFF across several months grouped by months

Tags: sql-server

I need to get this output at the bottom.

[image: Need to get the output]

Comment: hahahaha, please do not post image. Post as formatted text instead. Please show your table schema, sample data and expected result Please also show your attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `MASTER..SPT_VALUES` this default SQL Server table which is used for creating **VIRTUAL TABLES**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
ID INT ,ST_DATE DATE,ED_DATE DATE,DURATION INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5555,'30-Mar-2020','02-Apr-2020',4)

Declare @T1 Table(
ID INT,WK_MONTH VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @T1 values(5555,'Mar-2020')
Insert into @T1 values(5555,'Apr-2020')
select * from @T
select * from @T1
```

Main Query:

```
SELECT T.ID,FORMAT(DATEADD(D, NUMBER, T.ST_DATE),'MMM-yy') as [Work 
Month],COUNT(MONTH(DATEADD(D, NUMBER, T.ST_DATE) )) as [Absent Days]
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES cross apply @T t
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DD, T.ST_DATE,   T.ED_DATE)
GROUP BY FORMAT(DATEADD(D, NUMBER, T.ST_DATE),'MMM-yy'),T.ID
```

Output

```
ID  Work Month  Absent Days
5555    Apr-20  2
5555    Mar-20  2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to this, however the first part I am assuming that the work month is a date field on the first of each month. I am also assuming start and end date are date fields.

The code I would use is below. I have used "E" for employee table and "L" for Leave table for easy reading. I have also added comments in the code which should help understand.

```
-- Assuming the workmonth table is date field set to 1st of each month
SELECT E.EmpID, 
       E.WorkMonth, 
--- Below case statement is when start and end month are the same.
       CASE
           WHEN(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.StartDate)), (0))) = (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.EndDate)), (0)))
           THEN DATEDIFF(day, L.StartDate, L.EndDate) + 1 
---- Below case statement is when you want to calculate start to end of month.
           WHEN(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.StartDate)), (0))) = E.WorkMonth
           THEN DATEDIFF(day, L.StartDate, DATEADD(month, 1, E.WorkMonth))
---- Below case statement is when you want to calculate start of month to end date.
           WHEN(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.endDate)), (0))) = E.WorkMonth
           THEN DATEDIFF(day, E.WorkMonth, L.EndDate) + 1
       END StartMonth

FROM dbo.EmployeeTable AS E
     inner JOIN dbo.LeavTable AS L ON E.EmpID = L.EMPID
-- The join is where you can combine the  months joining tyo the first of the month.
                                           AND E.WorkMonth >= (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.StartDate)), (0)))
                                           AND E.WorkMonth <= (DAETEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, (0), CONVERT([DATETIME], L.EndDate)), (0)))
```